# Progressbar on file-upload to Amazon S3 for iOS?

Tags: ios, file-upload, amazon-s3, progress

I was using the services from [Parse](http://www.parse.com) a while back, and they had implemented an amazing feature for uploading data, with a method something like this:

```
PFFile *objectToSave...; //An image or whatever, wrapped in a Parse-file
[objectToSave saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        //Do stuff after upload is complete
    } progressBlock:^(int percentDone) {
        [someLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%@", percentDone, @"%"]];
    }];
```

Which let me keep track of the file-upload. Since Parse only let me upload max 10mb files, I chose to move to the cloud-area to explore a bit. I've been testing with Amazon's S3-service now, but the only way I can find how to upload data is by calling `[s3 putObject:request];`. This will occupy the main thread until it's done, unless I run it on another thread. Either way, I have no idea of letting my users know how far the upload has come. Is there seriously no way of doing this? I read that some browser-API-version of S3's service had to use Flash, or set all uploads to go through another server, and keep track on that server, but I won't do either of those. Anyone? Thanks.

My users are supposed to be uploading video with sizes up to 15mb, do I have to let them stare at a spinning wheel for an unknown amount of time? With a bad connection, they might have to wait for 15 minutes, but they would stare at the screen in hope the entire time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like I didn't quite do my homework before posting this question in the first place. I found [this great tutorial](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxIRFEQTW9XU8G/S3TransferManager-for-iOS-Part-I-Asynchronous-Uploads) doing exactly what I was asking for. I would delete my question, but I'll let it stay just in case it might help other helpless people like myself.

**Basically**, it had a delegate-method for this. Do something like this:

```
S3PutObjectRequest *por = /* your request/file */;
S3TransferManager *tm = /* your transfer manager */;

por.delegate = self;
tm.delegate = self;

[tm upload: por];
```

Then use this appropriately named delegate-method:

```
-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request 
    didSendData:(long long)bytesWritten 
    totalBytesWritten:(long long)totalBytesWritten 
    totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(long long)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{
    CGFloat progress = ((CGFloat)totalBytesWritten/(CGFloat)totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}
```

It will be called for every packet it uploads or something. Just be sure to set the delegates.

(Not sure if you need both delegates to be set though)

Comment: I ran into the same issue. How do you configure your Parse to store file to S3. Normally we will use PFFile to send it to mLab, should we install Amazon iOS SDK and save directly to the S3 and creat a URL field in our database to refer to the file in S3, fetch it through the URL if we need it?

Comment: @KesongXie Oh, I ditched Parse completely when I changed to Amazon, so I have no idea.